# Iteratively adding to Hash Map

Tags: java, hashmap

```
for(int i=0; i< n; i++) {
    hashMap.put("Name",name.get(i));
    hashMap.put("Website",website.get(i));
}
```

I would like to add multiple values to an HashMap iteratively
I want my output to be like this

1. Name: Anna    Website: www.anna.com
2. Name: kayden  Website: www.kayden.com
3. Name: fred    Website: www.fred.com
4. Name: george  Website: www.george.com

How do i add to the hashmap, I am not getting expected results.

Comment: Seems like you need more than 1 HashMap. An HashMap can only store 1 value for 1 key.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use a website object with url and name fields?

Comment: All i want to do is to iteratively add names and corresponding pages and be able to fetch or retrieve for use, i do not mind you suggesting a better approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing you want this instead:

```
for(int i=0; i< n; i++) {
    hashMap.put(name.get(i), website.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The values should be used as Map's key.

```
map.put("Anna","www.anna.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
for(int i=0; i< n; i++) {
    hashMap.put("Name:"+name.get(i),"Website:"+website.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a series of (Name, Website) pairs that you want to store. I suggest creating a class with `name` and `website` fields. Its toString should produce the string you want for the pair. You can then use any Set implementation, including HashSet, to store the pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for your data and add the objects of those class to the hashmap against a logical key.

Here is the sample code, lets suppose you create a class called Record with the attributes name and website:

```
class Record { 

    String name;

    String website;


    public Record(String name, String website) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.website = website;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }


}
```

Code to add the objects against key, modify the code to add the records against your desired key:

```
Map<String,Record> recordsMap = new HashMap<String, Record>();
for(int i=0; i< n; i++) {
    Record record  = new Record(name.get(i), website.get(i));
    recordsMap.put(name.get(i), record);


}
```

Comment: how do i retrieve the values from hashmap without knowing the keys since it was added iteratively?

Comment: @fumzy This i what I mentioned, you need to pick a logical key with which you can identify your records. Lets suppose, you add a new attribute in your Record class called RecordId of type Integer. Then you can assign each record an Id while creating the instance of that class. And you can use that RecordId as the key for your Hashmap

Comment: would try that now, thanks

Comment: @fumzy Good Luck, let me know the outcome :-)

Comment: May I know the reason of a downvote here?